# How to prevent duplicate insertion in azure table in multitasking environment?

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure

I have an multitasking application, where multiple tasks are running at a same time. Each of the task checks if a recordId is already present in azure table or not. If not it adds it. My problem is, though I have applied check on recordId still duplicate entries are getting added.

```
public async Task<bool> TryExecuteAsync(ServiceCommandMessage commandMessage, CancellationToken token, IProgress<string> progress)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            var isSuccessful = true;

            return await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                var watch = new Stopwatch();
                watch.Start();

                try
                {
                    StoreFourSqaureMetadata(id);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {                    
                    isSuccessful = false;
                    throw ex;
                }

                watch.Stop();

                return isSuccessful;
            }, token);
        }
public static void StoreFourSqaureMetadata(string Id)
    {
        var noDataAvailable = "No data available".Trim();
        try
        {               
            var d = IsExist(Id); //Checking if Id already exist in Table
            if (d != null) return;
            //If not add to table

        }
    }
```

Comment: On a side note, assuming that this is running in some sort of web environment, you're probably not going to get a lot of benefit by throwing the `StoreFourSqaureMetadata()` call out onto a separate thread and then awaiting it. Making everything async is great, and probably the right way to go if you have scalability concerns, but you're not gaining anything, either in performance or responsiveness, by spinning up new threads; indeed, you're almost certainly hurting yourself.

Comment: You may have to redesign your table to stop duplicates or consider using blob AcquireLease as a simple distributed mutex.  Regarding the latter, you will need to change the method StoreFourSquareMetadata so that the code following //if not add to table first attempts to AcquireLease.  A successful AcquireLease means the current node has the mutex and can add the id, whereas a failed Acquire means another node is already adding that Id.

Answer (score 2):

I think that best solution to your problem has two fairly self-explanatory parts: (1) Create a unique key on the appropriate columns in the table; and (2) catch the error after a failed insert.

The unique key is really the important part. It's the only way to ensure that this sort of thing isn't happening, because the DB is the only piece of your architecture that's going to be able to guarantee that sort of consistency.

In places where this is likely to be a problem, I use a pattern something like this. First, I have a set of helper methods that help me with retries:

```
/// <summary>
/// Try a given async action 'n' times or until it succeeds.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="times">The number of times to retry the action</param>
/// <param name="action">The action to retry</param>
/// <param name="pauseInMilliseconds">The amount of time in milliseconds to pause between retries (defaults to 0)</param>
public async static Task<T> RetriesAsync<T>(this int times, Func<int, Task<T>> action, int pauseInMilliseconds)
{
    var attempt = 0;
    var result = default(T);
    while (attempt < times)
    {
        try
        {
            result = await action(attempt);
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            attempt++;
            if (attempt >= times)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        if (pauseInMilliseconds > 0)
        {
            await Task.Delay(pauseInMilliseconds);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then I have methods that check to see if the row exists; if it does, it returns it; if it doesn't, it inserts and then returns it. That works kind of like this:

```
private async Task<Customer> CreateOrGetCustomer(IEntities db, int customerId)
{
    var customer = await db.Customers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.CustomerId == customerId);
    if (customer == null)
    {
        customer = new Customer { CustomerId = customerId };
        db.Customers.Add(customer);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    return customer;
}
```

I then call the method with a retry like this:

```
var customer = await 2.RetriesAsync(async x => CreateOrGetCustomer(db, customerId));
```

I'm sure there are more elegant ways of doing it, but it works -- at least, it works if you've got all the appropriate unique keys configured on your table.

I *think* that those two parts are fairly self-explanatory, but let me know if you need more guidance around them, or if they won't work for you for some reason.

Comment: Please note I am storing data in Azure table and not in SQL database, I cant have unique key there :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a common class of problem called a [Race Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and they can be particularly troublesome, especially when you're dealing with databases.

The problem comes when two (or more) threads are trying to add the same ID value at the same time.  They both check the table in the database to see if the ID exists, both find that it doesn't, then both add a new record for it.

There are many ways to get this to work: a stored procedure that locks the table while it checks and inserts, a unique key or index on the ID field to force failure on multiple insert attempts, a single thread responsible for the inserts, a thread-safe collection of inserted IDs that you check and insert inside a lock, etc.  Which method you choose depends largely on the requirements of your application.

If you're not worried about a few delays in getting the data into the database directly, you could use a lock in your `StoreFourSqaureMetadata` method to ensure that only one thread is updating the database at any one time:

```
private static readonly object _lock = new object();

public static void StoreFourSqaureMetadata(string Id)
{
    var noDataAvailable = "No data available".Trim();
    lock(_lock)
    {
        try
        {               
            var d = IsExist(Id); //Checking if Id already exist in Table
            if (d != null) 
                return;
            //If not add to table
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

This will absolutely prevent two threads from trying to add records at the same time, at the expense of making all of the operations queue up and run through the code one at a time.  It will prevent the threads from doing multiple inserts of the same data, but you end up reducing your overall throughput.

Without more information about your specific problem I can't really suggest a more specific solution.  For instance, if you are always getting fresh IDs and don't have to concern yourself with what's already in the database you can maintain a list in memory and only lock long enough to check and insert an entry in that list... the possibilities are endless :P

Comment: I have already used lock, and it did not work for me. No SP or unique key will work as its not a SQL DB instead its an azure table(NOSQL)

Comment: I don't recall that being mentioned before... it certainly does change things.  Sorry I missed it... this is a Distributed problem, not a Threading problem.  Your 'threads' can be running on different computers, so a lock on one of them isn't going to mean a damned thing to the rest.

Comment: What is the alternate then? I am stuck here since last 7 days :(

Comment: Depends... Is it important that the first item in be preserved?  If not then you can use either [InsertOrReplace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh452242.aspx) or [InsertOrMerge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh452241.aspx) to ensure only one record, although it will have the data from the last processed message.

Comment: You need to make sure that the `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` for both inserts is identical.  These two together make up the primary key for the entity in Table Storage.  Calculate `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` from the `Id` field and you'll get uniqueness - first record only if you use standard `Insert`, last record if you use `InsertOrUpdate`.

Comment: Rowkey is unique, but Partition key is my restaurant id which few of the apis  return(which are same). Isvenueexists is the function which checks if that is already present in table or not and then do the add operation. Secondly, I have used InsertOrMerge only.

Comment: there is no method as InsertOrUpdate

Comment: If you can't have a unique Primary Key, you're flat out of luck.  That's the way Azure Table Storage works.  Don't expect SQL-like functionality from it, that's not what it's for.  (I meant `InsertOrReplace` of course.  Typo - I don't use Azure often.)

Comment: Combination of rowkey and partition key should  be unique, and I have the unique combination. Problem is Azure table is allowing duplicate partition key to be inserted, this is what i need to stop :)

Comment: Just one more reason - out of a whole long list - not to use Azure Table Storage, IMO. ATS is a POS to be avoided if at all possible, in my experience.